# xpath expression to retrieve name/value pairs disregarding namespaces that precede the names

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have the following xml snippet that I need to extract values from with xpath expressions in xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:NotificationRequest xmlns:ns0="http://www.somedomain.com/schemas/message/Request">
   <ns1:Header xmlns:ns1="http://www.somedomain.com/schemas/common/Header">
      <ns1:Element1>Element 1 Value</ns1:Element1>
      <ns1:Element2>Element 2 Value</ns1:Element2>
   </ns1:Header>
   <ns0:MessageValues>
      <ns0:MessageValue>
         <ns0:Name>Name1</ns0:Name>
         <ns0:Value>Value1</ns0:Value>
      </ns0:MessageValue>
      <ns0:MessageValue>
         <ns0:Name>Name2</ns0:Name>
         <ns0:Value>Value2</ns0:Value>
      </ns0:MessageValue>
   </ns0:MessageValues>
</ns0:NotificationRequest>
```

To retrieve the value of Element1 or Element2 disregarding the name space I know I can use an xsl/xpath expression as follows:

```
   <xsl:value-of select="//*[local-name()='Element1']" />
```

However, I'm struggling with the xpath expression to retrieve the value of the ns0:Value nodes in the Name/Value pair section. For example, what does the expression look like to get "Value1" or "Value2" that works regardless of the namespace. I know how to do it with namespaces, but i can't use that method because the xml file that I need to process re-uses namespaces w/in the same document.

Comment: Show how would you do it with namespaces, it should be easy convert to be using `local-name()`s

Comment: With namespaces it looks like this:

<xsl:value-of select="//*[ns0:Name = 'Name1']/ns0:Value"/>

Comment: "*the xml file that I need to process re-uses namespaces w/in the same document.*" What exactly does that mean? As a general rule, you should not ignore namespaces, because paths using only local names are by definition ambiguous - and performance suffers too.

Answer (score 1):

> "With namespaces it looks like this: `<xsl:value-of select="//*[ns0:Name = 'Name1']/ns0:Value"/>`"

You can use `and` operator to check for both element's `local-name` and value. In addition to that, `Value` is not child of `Name` it is `following-sibling` instead :

```
//*[local-name()='Name' and .='Name1']/following-sibling::*[local-name()='Value']
```

Comment: See my alternative as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the namespaces really carry no information and only get in the way, the best thing to do is to get rid of them in a preprocessing pass rather than cluttering all your XPath expressions in this way.

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="get-rid-of-namespaces">
 <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
  <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates mode="#current"/>
 </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This question is tagged XSLT 1.0, so `mode="#current"` will not work.

Comment: Sorry, it's about a decade since I used XSLT 1.0 and one gets rusty.

Comment: Thanks everyone. You've supplied some great information that I can use to discuss with our customer.

Answer (score 0):

Har07's answer is very cool, but I've always done it the other way around. 
I select the node I want, then qualify it with the sibling node (also name my sibling node specifically rather than depending on it being the next one):

```
//*[local-name()='Value'][../*[local-name()='Name' and .='Name1']]
```

Great testing tool with your scenario and my answer: 
http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/38270fcac4d94d3d59b47069301f4456

We do this a lot in EDI with REF segments for example:

```
<ns0:X12_00401_850 xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/EDI/X12/2006">
    <ns0:REF>
        <REF01>IA</REF01>
        <REF02>Name1</REF02>
    </ns0:REF>
    <ns0:REF>
        <REF01>VN</REF01>
        <REF02>Name1</REF02>
    </ns0:REF>
</ns0:X12_00401_850>
```

You basically want to lookup the REF02 for VN for example...

```
//*[local-name()='REF']//*[local-name()='REF02'][..//*[local-name()='REF01' and text()='VN']]
```

I thought by adding this second example it would help people doing BizTalk and EDI to find same question/answer.

Comment: To ignore namespace is never a good choice. All good XPath implementations expose an API to bind namespaces to prefixes. Besides that, an expression with a predicate testing just for `local-name()` might select two elements in different namespaces but with the same local part of the QName.

Comment: I was just answering the guy's questions (with an alternative to the accepted answer) which was how to do it without namespaces. We do it a lot in BizTalk where there is one namespace only at the root.